# Concatenate SQL results into a single string with a counter

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

**Say I have a table as shown below**

```
 Product_Id      Description
  BX01              Desc 1
  BxX1              Desc 2
  Dss3              Desc 3
  HHXY              Desc 4
```

I want the result exactly like: `1 - BX01, 2 - BxX1, 3 - Dss3, 4 - HHXY`

**I have this query:**

```
DECLARE @ProID VARCHAR(8000)  
SELECT @ProID = COALESCE(@ProID + ' - ', '') + Product_Id FROM TABLE      
SELECT @ProID
```

but the return values is only :

`BX01,- BxX1,- Dss3,- HHXY`.

The counting is lacking.

**How to do that?**

thanks

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT() is not possible for this scenario.  I can't get the exact output I wanted as stated above.

Comment: It is, check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( 
            CONCAT( @rownum := @rownum + 1, '-', Product_Id ) 
            SEPARATOR ',' 
       ) AS data
FROM table, ( select @rownum := 0 ) r
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17548/11)

This will build the result you wanted by grouping all the column data and adding a counter before it, separating each data with a comma.

Note: You can remove `, ( select @rownum := 0 ) r` though. Depends on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In `mysql` it would be ,

```
SET @a:=0;

SELECT CONCAT( @a:=@a+1,'-',Product_Id) FROM TABLE ;
```